# AngularJS. Filters

Tags: angularjs, filter

Trying to understand filers in AngularJS. I have the following code seeding articles from JSON to the home page.

```
<div ng-repeat='article in articlesList | filter:filters'>
  <span>{{article.category}}</span>
  <h1>{{article.title}}</h1>
  <p>{{article.short_desc}}</p>
</div>
```

I also have navigation, which I want to act as a filter, so instead of going to a new page, it will just filter article out from home page by category.

```
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a ng-click="filters.category = 'home'">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a ng-click="filters.category = 'activity'">Home</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

My JSON looks like this

```
{

    "article1": {
        "id":"1",
        "category": "home",
        "title": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.",
        "short_desc": "Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit",
        "images": [
            "img/article-img1.jpg"
        ]
    },

    "article2": {
        "id":"2",
        "category": "activity",
        "title": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.",
        "short_desc": "Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit",
        "images": [
            "img/article-img2.jpg"
        ]
    },

}
```

I am fetching data from it with this controller

```
app.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('pages/articles.json')
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.filters = {}
            $scope.articlesList = data;
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            alert('Something is wrong with JSON')
        })
});
```

I am trying to figure out the right way to set up the Filter. Looking for a solution or some article dealing with similar problem.

Or maybe filtering is not the best option for this task. I appreciate any suggestions/best practices.

Comment: `ng-repeat='article in articlelist | filter:categoryFilter' ` unless I am misunderstanding the problem. Also one of your curly braces is outside the quote on your ng-click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept making edits to my comment, so I figured I would just make an answer to the question.

In order to use your filter, you're going to need to do something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat='article in articlesList | filter:categoryFilter'>
  <span>{{article.category}}</span>
  <h1>{{article.title}}</h1>
  <p>{{article.short_desc}}</p>
</div>
```

And then, in your navigation bar (assuming they have the same scope, if not then the answer would be mildly different), you would do something akin to this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
      <a href="" class="active" ng-click="categoryFilter.category=1">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="" ng-click="categoryFilter.category=2">Press</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

I don't have any data to test this out thoroughly. If it doesn't work, please provide a few (~5) objects in the JSON array so that I can test it out on a plunkr. Also the HTML in your body tag would help greatly.

[Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) is the API documentation for filters, with a few examples that may help you understand filters a little more.

## EDIT

Since you updated your information, I got [This Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Cumj6eZJHJtDeGOO8fLb?p=preview) working.

I'll break each part down:

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="home">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="dataCtrl">
    <nav>
      <a ng-click="categoryFilter.category='Home'">Home</a>
      <a ng-click="categoryFilter.category='Activity'">Activity</a>
      <a ng-click="resetCategoryFilter()">Reset</a>
      
      <span style="float:right;"><input type="text" ng-model="categoryFilter.title"></span>
    </nav>
    Your Current Filters Applied Are: {{categoryFilter}}
    <div ng-repeat="item in data | filter:categoryFilter">
      {{item.title}}
    </div>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Now for the HTML, you'll see that I have just 1 controller being set. This makes it so that all of these items are in the same parent. If you have a wrapper DIV, I suggest putting the `ng-controller` on that div.

You'll notice that I didn't put the elements in an `<ul>` or `<li>` tags. That's because I forgot. It should still work inside them.

That being said, You'll notice my code uses the $scope variable throughout. You seem to have a basic working knowledge of the $scope variable, so I'll leave it mostly alone. The one thing is the function I added to the scope, the `resetCategoryFilters()` function. It's a simple enough function: it takes all of the keys and sets their values to undefined so that the filters object is reset to base. I initialized the categoryFilters in the scope because... well I'm not sure, it just bothers me if I don't.

### Javascript

// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('home', []);

```
app.controller('dataCtrl',function($scope){
  $scope.categoryFilter = {
    category:undefined,
    title:undefined,
    short_desc:undefined
  };
  
  $scope.resetCategoryFilter = function(){
    for(var x in $scope.categoryFilter){
      $scope.categoryFilter[x]=undefined;
    }
  }
  
  $scope.data = [
    {
        "id":"1",
        "category": "Home",
        "title": "20 Useful Things around your House",
        "short_desc": "Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit",
        "images": [
            "img/article-img1.jpg"
        ]
    },

     {
        "id":"2",
        "category": "Activity",
        "title": "Carpe the Diem",
        "short_desc": "Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit",
        "images": [
            "img/article-img2.jpg"
        ]
    }


    ];//Here, instead of hard-coding the data like I did, use the $http service to get the values
});
```

You'll notice where I simply hard-coded the data. Since I was using Plunkr, I could have set that data off in a different page, but it was just easier to have it there. Use the $http service and the .get method to populate the $scope.data array.

#### *Remarks About Your Javascript*

I noticed that the indexes in the JSON you were giving were hard coded. I deleted them, making the `data` object an Array of objects, as opposed to an object of objects. Easy to loop through an array, difficult to loop through an object.

Hopefully this answers your question.

Comment: I have updated the data. I have posted the JSON and controller I use to fetch data from it and now I need a way to filter that data with ng-click and filter.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution and explanations. I will keep learning :)